# Aliasing in heatmap gridlines

Tags: matplotlib

I am following the tutorial on matplotlib for creating heatmaps: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html#a-simple-categorical-heatmap

I run the code with a slight modification, which is changing the following line:

```py
ax.grid(which="minor", color="w", linestyle='-', linewidth=3)
```

into

```py
ax.grid(which="minor", color="black", linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
```

I get the following plot:
[image]

There is a small distortion in the line separating the second row with the third row. The line is not exactly between the rows of cells.

Zooming in on this distortion we have:

[image]

I believe this is due to aliasing? Is there a simple fix for this?

Comment: Is this visible after you save the figure using plt.savefig?

Comment: This is snapping of the gridline to the nearest full pixel.  You can turn the snapping off (`snap=False`) or save with more pixels.

Comment: @JodyKlymak It seems that passing `snap=False` to `imshow` does not resolve my issue. How do I increase the amount of pixels? by setting `dpi=300` in the `savefig` command?

Comment: The snap goes on the ax.grid method.    But yes, you can increase the dpi on the save fig command.